# Count the Calls group by months

Tags: javascript, graph, grid

Data: you can See in below image:

i want display this data like this:(how many calls are there in particular months)

```
     Name      Jan     Feb     March    April    May
    Staff      0       1        1        0        0
    Account    0       0        1        0        3
```

and i want to do this the same for all the months.

[image: I have data like this]

for Graph i wrote a function like this:(but i tried using same logic for table also, but that doesn't seem to work.)

Anyone can help me how to do the same thing in table

```
getGraphData2( data,config) {
        var year = new Date().getUTCFullYear()-1;
        var month = new Date().getMonth()+10;
        var fullMonths = config.Filter.filter(f => f.type === "Monthly");
        var monthsThisYear = config.Filter.filter(f => f.type === "Monthly" && f.key <= month && f.key > (month - 12));
        var monthsLastYear = config.Filter.filter(f => f.type === "Monthly" && f.key > (12 - (12 - monthsThisYear.length)));
        var months = [];
        months.push(...monthsThisYear);
        months.push(...monthsLastYear);

        var labels = months.map(m => m.value);
        var targetTypes = this.state.resultsGraph.map(m => ({Name: m.Name}));
        var fData = {};
        targetTypes.forEach(f => {
            fData[f.Name] = { label: f.Name, data: fullMonths.map(m => 0) };
        });
        if (this.state.results !== null) {
            for (var c = 0; c < this.state.resultsGraph.length; c++) {
                var call = this.state.resultsGraph[c];
                if (call !== undefined && call !== null) {
                    var cDate = new Date(call.Call_Date_vod__c); //ConvertToDate(call.call_Date_vod__c);
                    if (cDate != null && ((cDate.getMonth() + 1) <= month && cDate.getFullYear() === year) || (month < (cDate.getMonth() + 1) && cDate.getFullYear() === (year - 1))) {
                        var targetType = call.Name;
                        if (targetType !== undefined && targetType !== null) {
                            var actData = fData[targetType];
                            if (actData !== undefined && actData !== null)
                                actData.data[cDate.getMonth()] = actData.data[cDate.getMonth()] + 1;
                            else {
                                actData = fData["NoTarget"];
                                actData.data[cDate.getMonth()] = actData.data[cDate.getMonth()] + 1;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            var actData = fData["NoTarget"];
                            actData.data[cDate.getMonth()] = actData.data[cDate.getMonth()] + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        fData = Object.keys(fData).map(k => fData[k]);

        fData = fData.filter(f => f.data.filter(d => d > 0).length > 0);

        for (var i = 0; i < fData.length; i++) {
            var fdat = fData[i];
            var data = fdat.data;
            fdat.data = months.map(m => data[(m.key - 1)]);
        }


        var ds = fData.map((m, index) => ({
            label: m.label,
            data: m.data,
            stack: "stack1",
            backgroundColor: labels.map(l => (this.props.selectGraphFilter === l) ? getCanvasPattern(config.BackgroundColor[index]) : config.BackgroundColor[index]),
            hoverBackgroundColor: labels.map(l => (this.props.selectGraphFilter === l) ? getCanvasPattern(config.HoverBackgroundColor[index]) : config.HoverBackgroundColor[index]),
        }));


        var graphData = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: ds,
        };

        return graphData;
 }
```

Comment: Can you share what your original data looks like?

Comment: @Domino987 i have attached the screenshot of what's my original data looks like?

Answer (score 0):

How about to aggregate it like this?

```
const data = this.state.resultsGraph.reduce(
  (actData, call) => {
    if (actData) {
      actData[call.Name][
        `${call.Call_Date_vod__c.getMonth()} ${call.Call_Date_vod__c.getFullYear()}`
      ] =
        (actData[call.Name][
          `${call.Call_Date_vod__c.getMonth()} ${call.Call_Date_vod__c.getFullYear()}`
        ] || 0) + call.Call;
    }

    return actData;
  },
  {
    Staff: {},
    Account: {}
  }
);
```